# Update Decimal valued fields in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to do the following to my database:

```
UPDATE Addresses

SET Latitude = 1000, Longitude = 1000
WHERE Latitude IS NULL AND Longitude IS NULL
```

1000 is not a valid latitude or longitude. `Latitude` and `Longitude` are new columns in my database, and I don't want any of the fields to be null. I handle invalid latitude and longitude values in my application, but having them null creates difficulties.

When I try to run this query, I get the following error:

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 3
Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The datatypes of the Latitude and Longitude column are both `Decimal(18,15)`. I assume that I have to write these decimal entries in a particular way, but I can't work out what it is.

Could someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You are overflowing your specified parameters for the datatype.**

`DECIMAL(18,15)` means you have 18 total places, and 15 of those are right of the decimal.  This leaves 3 places left of the decimal, and 1000 is a **four digit number**.

You need to either change the datatype to something like `DECIMAL(18,14)` or use a value like `999.999999999999999`.

Comment: Ouch, right. Not floating point. I should have noticed that. Thanks for the heads up.